# How to configure kafka cluster for batch processing

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to provide only certain number of new rows to a DB(consumer) using Kafka connect. For which I've configured the source config file as

This is how the source.properties looks:

```
 name=source-postgres
 connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
 tasks.max=1
 batch.max.rows = 10
 connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://<URL>/postgres?user=postgres&password=post
 mode=timestamp+incrementing
 timestamp.column.name=updated_at
 incrementing.column.name=id
 topic.prefix=postgres_
```

This is the content of sink property file

```
name=dbx-sink
batch.size=5
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

# The topics to consume from - required for sink connectors like this one
topics=postgres_users

# Configuration specific to the JDBC sink connector.
# We want to connect to a SQLite database stored in the file test.db and auto-create tables.
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://<URL>:35000/postgres?user=dba&password=nopasswd
auto.create=true
```

But this doesn't have any effect, whenever a new row is available it's getting inserted to the DB (consumer). So, I added another config parameter to the sink `batch.size=10`. This also has no effect.

When I am starting the connect-standalone.sh script I can see the batch.max.rows = 10 on the console.

What am I doing wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`batch.max.rows` will send 10 rows per batch; it won't limit the number of rows sent in total.

Comment: How to limit it then?
Will this help table.poll.interval.ms?

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you want to do. You only want to pull 10 rows of data, even if there are more available?

Comment: I have taken 10 as an example. It can be 100 or more. What I want is when the producer have 100 new entries at that time to make it available to the consumer. Not to make available a row whenever it's available for consumption. I want to make entry to the sink as a batch of rows not small chunks.

Comment: Robin, do you know how to delay the message push from source. I am using kafka connect.